# Shell hangs when assigning command result to a variable

Tags: linux, shell, command-substitution

My original problem was to kill a process & its children when timeout. And I found GNU `timeout` quite a good choice.

However, in this testcase, things become weird:

Assume that we have a `test1.sh` like this:

```shell
#!/bin/sh
# test1.sh
output=`timeout 2 ./run.sh`
echo $output
```

and `run.sh` like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
# run.sh
sleep 8s&
```

Intuitively we should expect `test1.sh` exits instantly, since `init` will take charge of that silly `sleep` process and `run.sh` will then exits.

However:

```shell
sh-4.2$ time ./test1.sh

real    0m8.022s
user    0m0.013s
sys     0m0.003s
```

And if I create this `test2.sh`:

```shell
#!/bin/sh
# test2.sh
timeout 2 ./run.sh
```

```shell
sh-4.2$ time ./test2.sh

real    0m0.014s
user    0m0.003s
sys     0m0.007s
```

So, obviously we hit something wrong during command substitution, but why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be the way you have in shell script --

```
`timeout 2 ./run.sh`
```

-- you are using command substitution, so as long as the command has not finished execution, substitution cannot be done, because the output is not there...this may explain the output you are seeing.

Try this to see a similar outcome....

```
echo "hello `sleep 2 &`"
```

Another script of interest --

```
$ cat y.sh
echo "hi"
sleep 2 &
echo "bye"
sleep 2 &
```

Run using

```
echo "hello `sh y.sh`"

$time sh y.sh
hi
bye

real    0m0.006s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.004s

$time echo "hello `sh y.sh`"
hello hi
bye

real    0m2.008s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.000s
```

---

[This page](http://ajhaupt.blogspot.com/2011/03/background-processes-and-file.html) explains more about the relationship between background process and file descriptor. Basicly:

> Background (better: forked) processes inherit the file descriptors,
>   and Running a command in backticks means to collect its stdout until
>   its stdout is closed

Comment: Yes, your example clarifies things better! But I think, in my example, `run.sh` should *exits* since its original children is taken over by `init` ?

Comment: yes, it will be taken over by `init`, but its execution is still not finished.....so the output is not ready yet to be substituted....

Comment: pls see my second example to validate this....`y.sh` should exit pretty soon, but due to running in background, the `echo` command takes more than `2secs` to finish...fun stuff :)

Comment: ok, if I change `run.sh` as this: `sleep 8s&; date; exit 0`, so its result should be thought as *finished*? Actually I'm not sure what is defined as 'execution finished' :)

Comment: execution finished means process has finished execution and its entire output is available to be used via `command substitution `

Comment: No, that will still not do it, because when you execute `run.sh` it will exit pretty soon, but when you put `run.sh` for `command substitution `,  it is running for 8secs, before its output is there...hope it helps.

Comment: hmm, is it because that, the background process still holds the output file descriptor, so, even its father exits and its ppid changes, another process that reads the file descriptor won't stop?

Comment: increase the second `sleep` in my example to `4` or more to validate your reasoning :)

Comment: Thanks! the discussion helps much!